# How to generate 0-150V adjustable DC output?

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply

I wish to generate a voltage range of 0 - 150V output @ 2A Max to drive an actuator, and I don't really have a lot of great ideas at this point.

I have 2 power sources available, one is 220V AC, another is 150V fixed DC. Both come with enough current and power output.

I'm thinking about using transformer to convert the 220V AC to say 380V DC, then step it down. Problem is obviously there are regulators, programmable ones that allows you to bang out voltage as high as 60 but nothing more.

I have done the 60V fixed conversion in the past, but obviously the challenge I'm facing now is quite different.

Can someone please help me?

Edit: here are some more details about the actuator driver:

The accuracy of the voltage, or shall we say the resolution: ideally <1V, but <3V is also acceptable, in other words, for max voltage, if the final outcome is something like 153 volts or 147 volts, it should be fine.

Current: No need to worry about the current. Just the voltage.

Frequency/speed at which the voltage changes: 20KHz

Insulation from the user, isolation between primary side and the secondary side, isolation from the control unit (an MCU of course).

No preference on the input types since it's fixed.

Controlling (the control signal which decides what voltage to output) is purely digital, most likely over spi or uart interface.

Efficiency: no strong preference, but should be reasonably high.

Load: the load is capacitive.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to buy one. So would you please provide a link to the 60 V programmable regulator you are thinking about (or the closest to it that you can quickly find?) Knowing what would serve your needs (at a lower voltage) would clear up many questions I have in mind.

Comment: Details of the actuator are also required.

Comment: Well -- what accuracy of voltage? Should current limit be adjustable as well? Or is that just the nominal/max capacity? How fast does it need to vary? The output is hazardous voltage; it at least needs adequate insulation from users, but does it also need isolation? What about control inputs: isolated from the input (mains) or actuator (output) additionally? What are desired inputs, analog control voltages, current loop, digital interface (which)? What about efficiency? And most of all: what is your capability, how badly do you need it and how capable are you (given a little help)?

Comment: @periblepsis Hi, thanks for replying. I hope I didn't mislead everybody - that 60V example was merely there to show what I roughly expect things will be done. It was a fly-back design whereas what I want now most likely will be buck or buck-boost.  And no, even if I wanted to settle, 60V would be a far cry from 150V or say 130V, which is a voltage that has potential to work on my current project.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi, thank you for getting back to me. To avoid those "saw tooth" pattern, we hope the resolution/accuracy can be below 1 volt. Since the max voltage would be 150 V, sub-volt resolution should be enough. If that's difficult, less than 3 volts should also be acceptable, just a matter of effort vs outcome.  In other words, if the final outcome is something like 153 volts or 147 volts, it should be fine.  There is no need to worry about the current, just the voltage. The frequency is expected to be at the magnitude of 20Khz. Yes isolation and insulation. Yes isolation from input.

Comment: @TimWilliams There is no particularly preferred input, since the input is fixed, if you were talking about the control signal which tells the final product what voltage to output, of course it's digital, most likely over spi or uart interface. Efficiency isn't really high on the list as we are more concerned about getting it done than getting it done well, and we can always rig a bunch of fan and dissipate all the heat. My capability is of course quite limited but I can find external help. I want it pretty bad lol

Comment: 20kHz meaning the output can change this often, the output frequency or bandwidth? What are the load characteristics, is it nonlinear? Reactive, capacitive or inductive?

Comment: @TimWilliams The output can change this often. But how is it different from output frequency? I think I need to emphasize that the output is DC. The load is capacitive.

Comment: Why not juste a 300W/150VDC off-the-shelf SMPS? As reference "https://www.digikey.de/en/products/detail/sl-power-electronics-manufacture-of-condor-ault-brands/TF3000A150K/14309063" ... has an I2C interface (Most likely SMBus). 150V/20A so plenty of spare power. If this supply is not needed for a hobby project, i would buy one, as it will be way cheaper overall!

Comment: Sample rate, bandwidth (center) and bandwidth (baseband) are all related, but slightly different things -- it helps to be clear. Since it's a capacitive load, is there means to sink current from it, i.e. should the source be a general purpose amplifier, or a supply with 'down regulation'? Or will DC load current always be sufficient for the falling edge and a unipolar (single pass device) do the job?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent No we intend to use it as a component of a larger product so off the shelf products won't do. We need a high degree of integration.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim, once again thanks for getting back to me. I'm afraid I do not have sufficient knowledge equipped to answer most of those questions, but we can assume the current will be enough...

Comment: Is there anything you can say about the load, other than capacitive (and evidently DC resistive; unless, that's an AC peak or RMS current rating--?)?  For example if it's a piezo stack, it might not matter much what the DC is (a piezo transducer is easiest driven with AC; but that is one way to servo position of a microactuator, which also need not be fixed polarity but could be bipolar for double the working range), and DC current is zero and therefore discharge current must be supplied as well.

Comment: So far, it sounds like a somewhat higher voltage audio amp circuit might do, but that still leaves a number of variables (frequency response, DC and AC steady / RMS / max / peak +/- ratings) to arrive at a concrete design.

Comment: @TimWilliams I think I understand what you were trying to say, basically there will be "excess current" and it has to have some place to go right? Granted it has some resemblance with a Piezo stack, the overly simplified version would be a form of relay with coil controlling levers.    As for the audio amplifier circuit - will there actually be 150V ones?

Comment: @TimWilliams Quite ironically I found an amplifier board that we used before, when googling audio amplifiers. It's completely analogy, something we actively try to avoid.

Comment: You'll have a damn hard time avoiding analog when you're asking about analog quantities. :P Trivial solution: butt a DAC up to an amp. That's what most alternatives will be anyway ("power DAC"). Voltage is a bit higher than most stock designs, it would indeed be a custom job. The basic circuit is easily adaptable to this voltage range. A dozen transistors is likely easier to put together than a buck converter, let alone one fast enough for the stated bandwidth.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks! That may very well work. Per chance you have a reference design?